# Как сделать, чтобы анимация камеры могла быть повторена где угодно?

Tags: разработка-игр, unreal-engine-4, камера

Итак, моя проблема в том, что я не могу сделать скример для хоррора (анимацию камеры).

Cделать 2д скример с картинкой - это изи, но у меня 3д скример. То есть, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы камера во время скримера двигалась где угодно (в любой локации, в любом месте).

Это сложно понять, но я объясню: когда я делаю анимацию скримера в секвенсоре (в ue4), то при запуске этот скример работает только в одном месте, так как анимация объектов и камера прописана именно в определенной локации, но если скример начнется в совершенно другом месте, то камера все равно проигрывается в изначальном месте, а не в том, котором я нахожусь.

Так же то, что я хочу сделать, похоже на анимацию смерти в играх или анимацию QTE (моменты, где нужно быстро жать на одну и ту же кнопку, чтобы выполнить ивент). В играх такие моменты почему то работают, камера двигается в любой локации, а не только в определенных координатах.

Может, вы знаете как это сделать, чтобы все работало в любых координатах мира?

---

> *Скример - внезапно появляющийся страшный кадр в фильмах ужасов, видеороликах, компьютерных играх и т. п., сопровождаемый пронзительным криком или другим пугающим звуком.*

Comment: Я один ничего не понял? причем тут скример?

Comment: Вам стоит существенно переработать вопрос - убрать не относящиеся к делу детали и добавить больше технических моментов вашей цели и попыток реализации. Итак, дело в том что вы хотите записать реакцию камеры и проигрывать ее в произвольном месте, а не только в записанном?

Comment: да,именно так. То есть,если я запущу анимацию камеры в любом месте,то она проигрывается только в одном месте.вот мне и нужно сделать так,чтобы все работало в любых координатах мира